# What is the purpose of the Evocation wizard's Sculpt Spells feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard

The [School of Evocation wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#SchoolofEvocation)'s 2nd-level Sculpt Spells feature says:

> The chosen creatures **automatically succeed on their saving throws against the spell**, and they **take no damage** if they would normally take half damage on a successful save.

My English isn't that good and I'm a beginner, so I think that's the problem. Beginning at 2nd level, you can create "pockets of relative safety" - what does that mean?

So what is it for if it takes no damage? I understand it this way: If you choose more than 1 creature, then you take no damage.

I couldn't find anything and no one seems to have this kind of problem. I hope you understand it.

Comment: Your English may be a barrier to answering, but is your question regarding whether there is a difference if the target of the spell would normally not take any damage vs half damage on a save? For example, a Rogue with Evasion in the middle of a fireball making their save?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I think the question is *why* anyone would use Sculpt Spell, rather than the exact mechanics of how it works.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

### Sculpt Spells exists so you do not hurt your friends

When you cast a spell with an area of effect, everyone in the area is affected, including your friends / allies. Sculpt Spells lets you create "holes"(="pockets of relative safety") in the spell to keep your friends safe.

So an example use is:

1. You cast an area spell, say, [thunderwave](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thunderwave) in an area where friends and enemies are.
2. You have Sculpt Spells so you can choose up to 1 + 1 (spell level) friends in the area
3. The friends you chose are safe from your thunderwave and take no damage
4. Everyone else takes the spell's effect as normal

### Visual Example

These drawings may also help visually understand Sculpt Spell:

**1. Normal situation:**
[image: A caster (blue) casts a spell. Four other people are caught and harmed by the spell: Two blue, two red.]

**2. With Sculpt Spell:**
[image: A caster (blue) casts a spell. While the blue people are in the area where the spell is cast, they are in "pockets" and not affected by the spell. The two red characters are affected by the spell.]

Comment: +1, love the ridiculous drawings to overcome the language barrier.

Comment: -1, those circles don't look freehand.  (I kid)

Comment: -1 for triggering my "fireball explodes in a square!?!?!" OCD. I had just gotten over it with years of therapy.

Comment: @Jake For your own safety, _never_ watch any movie with explosions.

Comment: I changed the spell to thunderwave so that the square fits the spell's AoE.  (Feel free to change back, but it does fit your chose illustration better). @Jake You happy now?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast no because depending upon point of origin,  thunder wave should either be conical or a circle. In fact this is much worse, why did you do this to me? (I hope my jocular nature is coming through in this. I did not give a -1. In fact quite the opposite)

Comment: @Jake Per spell description, thunderwave is a cube.  square, as seen from a top view, as per the illustration. but thanks for explaining your joke.  :)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I hate when creators are wrong.

Comment: @Jake Yeah. Where did they get the idea that gnomes are a playable race?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast 3.5e.

Comment: @Jake AD&D 1e, 1978.

Comment: @keithcurtis it figures it would be Gygax' fault.

Answer (score 11):

There are several spells which target all creatures within a given area (such as Fireball), regardless of whether they are friendly to you or not. Sculpt Spell allows you to modify the area of such a spell so that certain creatures within are protected against the spell's effects. The most common usage for this would be to throw a Fireball into the middle of a combat without also damaging your melee teammates.

Answer (score 5):

*Sculpt Spell* is a feature that lets you shape a spell's area effect so that it does not hit the chosen creatures. The chosen creatures automatically succeed on the save and take no damage.

For Example:

The party is fighting monsters in a small room. The Wizard decides to use [*Fireball*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Fireball#content). *Fireball* will fill the entire room, so the Wizard uses *Sculpt Spell* while casting the *Fireball*. Now with *Sculpt Spell* affecting *Fireball*, the Wizard can make the ball of fire go around himself and his allies so only the monsters are hit.

Comment: Yes, @Ravery... It's the specific name of a Sorcerer ability.

Comment: @T.J.L. -- ah noted, and edited by doppelgreener. It's worth also noting the the Sorceres *Careful spell* metamagic is identical to *Sculpt Spell*

Comment: They're **very** different, actually. *Careful Spell* costs sorcery points, has no school restriction, target count is based on a stat, and grants automatic saves. *Sculpt Spells* has no cost, only works on evocations, target count is based on spell level, grants an automatic save **and** inflicts no damage when used with a save-for-half spell.

Comment: "the Wizard can make the ball of fire go around himself and his allies so only the monsters are hit."  RAW, the Wizard (evoker) can protect their allies, **but not themself** (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154381/in-al-can-an-evocation-wizard-protect-themself-from-their-own-spell-with-the-sc)

Answer (score 0):

The chosen creatures automatically succeed on their saving throws against the spell, and they take no damage if they would normally take half damage on a successful save.

They do not just take no damage it depends on what making a SAVE on the spell does.  It could be half damage, no damage, etc.  They simply automatically make their saving th

Comment: Hey, welcome to RPG SE, read [the tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and check [the help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. It looks like your answer isn't complete, you may want to finish it to help readers understand it.

Comment: What does this add that hasn't already been covered?